# Why icon can not display in page

Tags: css, icons, jquery-easyui

i have downloaded a icon from:

```
https://icons8.com/icon/new-icons/all
```

The icon name is icons8-santas-hat-64 with 64px png. After downloading, i changed its name to zw.png, and i put it down in

```
 jsui/easyui-1.5.3/themes/icons
```

Of course, I added config to icon.css. Here is url of icon.css:

```
jsui/easyui-1.5.3/themes/icon.css
```

Added content is:

```
 .icon-zw{ //add new icon
background:url('icons/zw.png') no-repeat center center;
}
.icon-blank{
background:url('icons/blank.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
.icon-add{
background:url('icons/edit_add.png') no-repeat center center;
}
 .....
```

Now I want to use it in my page, here is my html code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsui/easyui-1.5.3/themes/default/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsui/easyui-1.5.3/themes/icon.css">

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="" data-options="iconCls:'icon-zw'"></a>
```

But unlucky, it can not disappear in my page.

I have closed browser,  opened it for cleaning the cache, and visited website . But it failed again.

Who can help me?

Comment: You've added css rules for classes `.icon-*`. Did you add `class="icon-*"` anywhere on your page? Also, did you check console for errors?

Comment: @fen1x, I find in Elements that:

Comment: <span class="l-btn-icon icon-zw">&nbsp;</span>

Comment: @fen1x, what is mean of l-btn-icon